# Getting more than one value from dropdown in PHP

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I am populating a select box(drop down box) in PHP from a database.

```
function selBox(){
    conDB();
    $sql1 = "SELECT cname FROM course";
    $selResult = mysql_query($sql1);
    echo"<option value = 'default'>Select Course</option>";
        $rowNum = 0;
        while($selRows = mysql_fetch_array($selResult)){
        echo"<option value = " . $selRows[0] . ">" . $selRows[0] . </option>";
        }
    mysql_close();
}
```

The above function gets called in html like this:

```
<select name="delCourse"><?php selBox();?></select>
```

On the same page I get the value of what was selected in the drop box.

```
$Selected = $_POST['delCourse'];
            echo $Selected;
```

What happens is that I have a lot of courses in the database that populates to the dropbox.  The user makes a selection and this would then get put in $Selected to be forwarded to another function.

Problem:  Echoing the $Selected gives met a double answer like ScienceScience or MathematicsMathematics.  I can maybe do some string manipulation on this to get the right answer.  Is there another way of getting only a single answer back from what was selected in the dropbox?

Comment: Can you show the html output of the selectbox?

Comment: your missing a quote on the `</option>`

Comment: You are producing HTML dynamically and not using `htmlspecialchars` on all of the dynamic content. That's an XSS exploit waiting to happen. Use `echo htmlspecialchars($selRows[0])` instead and make sure to also pass the 2nd and 3rd arguments to `htmlspecialchars` so that it can do its job properly.

Comment: @ Mark. Sorry, I cant upload the image. Reputation to low.

Comment: @Waygood. Miss coppied the quote, edited the post. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got the answer to my question, by playing around with the function.  My function now looks like this:

```
function selBox($selValue){
    conDB();
    $sql1 = "SELECT cid, cname FROM course";
    $selResult = mysql_query($sql1);
    echo"<option value = 'default'>Select Course</option>";
        while($selRows = mysql_fetch_array($selResult)){
            $id = htmlspecialchars($selRows["cid"]) ;
            $course = htmlspecialchars($selRows["cname"]);
            echo "<option value='$id'>$course</option>";
        }
    $selValue = $_POST['delCourse'];
    mysql_close();
    return;
}
```

The function gets called like this from my other page:

```
    <select name="delCourse"><?php selBox($selValue);?></select>
```

The part of the switch statement that checks to see what was selected now looks like this:

```
    case "Delete Course":
            $selValue = "";
            $Selected = $selValue;
            echo $Selected;
            break;
```

I now get singles values by doing the above.  Now I can pass that value on again to the next function.